# How do I install Python Pandas for current python version

Tags: software-installation, python

I tried the following commands, but it is not working for me.

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
sudo easy_install pandas
python -c 'import sys; sys.path.append("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"); import pandas as pd;'
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install numpy
sudo pip install pandas
```

Comment: instead of this you should try Anaconda, hustle free installation for most of data science tools.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "not working".

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if you are using Ubuntu or a direct spin off, the easiest way to add to your Python 2.7 or Python 3.5 environments is to use Synaptic or the Ubuntu Software Center. The Ubuntu devs have gone to a lot of trouble to get the dependencies right and it will probably be more reliable than using easy-install or pip.

Simply open it, search for pandas and then install the required modules.

If you are comfortable with command line then you could also install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-pandas python-pandas-lib
```

If you don't want to add new packages to your distribution's python environment then installing *Anaconda Python Distribution* is also a valid solution.  This has the advantage that then libraries tend to be included, you don't affect your system's Python, you can easily upgrade to more recent Python (3.6 has just been released so will come to Anaconda soon)  and difficult to install packages like Numba are easy.